# Where can i find which version of java my pc uses

Tags: java, linux, windows

My pc runs windows 7. Where exactly can i find which java version my pc uses (Probably i use jdk_8 version)? My goal is to find which one of these versions:

- default-jre
- gcj-4.8-jre-headless
- openjdk-7-jre-headless
- gcj-4.6-jre-headless
- openjdk-6-jre-headless

is the equivalent for linux.

Comment: Define "uses". Different applications might be wired to use different JREs (if you have more than one installed). Is this for browser? Web server? IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the versions you've listed are Java 8 for linux. The closest is openjdk-7-jre-headless, but that's Java 7. The gcj is part of `gcc`. To determine the version in Windows you can run,

```
java -version
```

or

```
java -fullversion
```

Comment: Hey, thnx for your answer. Is it possible to give me a link for that java 7?

Comment: @captainmonk For what Linux distribution? And why not run the real Java 8 on Linux?

Comment: it is actually for a project thats why i'm trying to find the equivalent.

Comment: We did on windows and now i see it's version java 8 and now he sais it has to run in linux and it has to be on of these versions. Thats why i have to find the equivalent.

Comment: None of the above. Download and install java 7 for windows, or get java 8 for that linux.

Answer (score 1):

run this command in dos java -help to see all options and java -version
you should get the some details.

Comment: `Unrecognized option: --version` - manouti's version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Open a cmd terminal and run `java -version`.

Answer (score 1):

In the windows command line, enter the following command:

```
java -version
```

You can find more info here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/windows-cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

We use simple Java program: Create file `Check.java` , complie by `javac` tool and run this by `java` tool (these tools in directory `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` )

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Java Runtime Environment version is " + System.getProperty("java.version"));
    }

}

//        Result:
//        Java Runtime Environment version is 1.8.0_20
```